# I want to call a function when an element no longer has a specific class (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, class, hidden

I am making a plugin for a site where I can only use javascript. I want to execute code when il element with id = "gridview" no longer has the "hidden" class. Thank you for your help.

I already tried:

```
document.getElementById("id="eval_grid_tab"").addEventListener("click", start);
```

This is the html

```
<li id="eval_grid_tab"><a href="#gridview">Tabel</a></li>
<div id="gridview" class="rightsPanel smscTabsPanel hidden" style="height: 795px;">...</div>
```

Comment: What part of your code is removing the hidden class? Couldn't you just use execute your code then?

Comment: @Cully When I click on the a element the class "hidden" removes but I can't change the HTML code here so I need to do everything with js

Comment: You said you want to write a plugin. Do you mean a browser plugin or a greasemonkey script? Cause in those cases I think you're looking for a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: I'm making a plugin with a Tampermonkey script.

Comment: Then yes, a MutationObserver is what you need :)

Comment: Dankje wel! @icecub!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). It monitors the DOM for changes (like classes being removed / added) and triggers a callback function for you to use anyway you see fit.

```
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
var targetNode = document.getElementById('gridview');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
var config = { attributes: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
var callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type == 'attributes') {
            // Triggers when an attribute like 'class' is modified
            console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

Later, you can stop observing with

`observer.disconnect();`

Comment: Thank You for your answer! Where do I have to put my function to execute?

Comment: @Karmakip I would put the above code inside `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { .... });` to make sure it doesn't try to start the observer before the DOM is loaded. If you look at the code, you can see the comment "// Triggers when an attribute like 'class' is modified". The `console.log` underneath that is just an example. You can remove that and place your own code inside or call your function there.

Comment: I'm getting this error in the console: TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. (Ik zie dat je nederlands bent dat maakt me het mischien iets makelijker om te verstaan :) )

Comment: @Karmakip True, however this is an English website and your question is public. Even if you get your answer, other visitors with the same or simular question would not be able to read it if we communicate in Dutch. That error means `document.getElementById('gridview');` is failing. It cannot find this node in the DOM. Probably because the DOM is not loaded yet